# Does it bother anyone else that the site banner shorts pairs of IC pins together?

Tags: discussion

I realized it's a breadboard, and the ICs are not across the channel in the middle. It's been bothering me since.

Comment: You win the ElectroGeek Award for January! :-)

Comment: And you're fine with the LED integrated into the chips!?

Comment: It's didn't bother me until now, so thanks for that :)

Comment: @OlinLathrop Hahaha! That gave me a big laugh, thanks Olin :)

Comment: Wow, who would of thought this would be my best question?

Comment: Dang, I just realized it's a breadboard.

Comment: I had always written it off as perfboard, I never noticed the red and blue lines until now. I CAN'T UNSEE IT NOW.

Comment: Have anyone notices that the faint background has a schematic of the Atari?  The title block is on the far right.  Don't know if the schematic is real or made-up.

Comment: @Nick Alexeev It's real as far as I can determine. There's a version with better contrast [here](http://www.vintagegamingandmore.com/atari-2600-schematics/)(the top schematic).

Comment: Where are you seeing this Atari schematic? Can you post a screenshot? All I see in the page background is a square grid.

Comment: @JoeBaker it is probably because of your monitor or your gamma settings.. Plus, it is already dim and have poor contrast.. If you look carefully around the "breadboard" in the title, you will see it.

Comment: @JoeBaker  I've posted the screenshot to this thread.

Comment: If you look closely there are no springs in the breadboard, the holes are closed with white plastic ;o)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe this would be classified under artistic license. If you want a rundown of what is wrong, here's what I notice:

- There's no wiring
- The pin pitch is twice as coarse as the breadboard holes
- The 5x7 LED arrays are lit up without any apparent source of power
- There are LEDs in the IC packages
- There are 10 and 12 pin DIPs
- There aren't enough holes underneath the LED arrays
- All pins will be shorted to at least one other pin

It doesn't bother me.

Comment: I suppose that's true, but now I'm all the more bothered.

Comment: On reading "*There are 10 and 12 pin DIPs*", I searched a bit, and it turns out I just cannot find a single 10-pin DIP IC. Found many other components in 10-pin DIP (LED displays, DIP switches, resistor packs and of course sockets), but not a single regular IC! I wonder why that is?

Comment: Hmm, finally located a 10-pin DIP part: NTE1450, 5 Watt audio power amplifier. Why are 10-pin DIPs so uncommon?

Comment: @W5VO Have to ask.. where do you see a 12-pin DIP?

Answer (score 11):

No, because the type of breadboard we currently use looks kind of cool as the title -- but let's be honest, it is no good anyway. *Real* breadboards *always* look like this ;-)

[image]

---

Except when they look like this:

[image]

[It worked][DO NOT show Olin!!!].

Dude, you weren't, like, upgrading [Dolby SR](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rauschunterdr%C3%BCckungsverfahren) when you hacked this?

[image: Dolby Breadboard, Source:]

Comment: It might be interesting to have a site logo that spells out something with a messy breadboard design like that.

Comment: Yeah. That's why I said the current logo looks good to me. I might try to hack one, though...

Comment: @Kortuk: [something like this](https://www.circuitlab.com/aoteuhnsaoetnh)?

Comment: @PhilFrost that but with real components and for our header. The current header looks very nice currently though, although invalid.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a screenshot (enhanced) showing where to look for the ATARI title block.  If I look at my LCD monitor at 45° angle, it stands out a little bit more.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Even though it is short circuited, it looks nice. The display just needs a blue tint for a VFD look.